# Tokenise a String in C programming

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I know there have been other explanations on how to split a string into words but none of them seem similar to my program. I'm having difficulty finding the errors in my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int tokenise(char str[], int start, char result[]) {
    if (str[start] == "/o") {
        return -1;
    } else {
        result = str[start];
    }
}


int main() {    
    const int MAX_STRING = 256;
    char buffer[MAX_STRING];
    fgets(buffer, MAX_STRING, stdin);
    char result[256];
    int start;
    start = tokenise(buffer, 0, result);

    while ( start != -1 ) {
        printf("%s\n", result);
        start = tokenise(buffer, start, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an actual question?

Comment: Please use proper indentation in the future; it'll make your life much easier, and people much more likely to answer your questions. I've fixed it for you this time. Also, this code doesn't compile.

Comment: Yes, my program wont work and I can't figure out why

Comment: "Yes, my program wont work" What is your program supposed to do? Please provide example input, the expected output and the actual output.

Comment: My program is supposed to read in a line such as "hello world" and return each word on a separate line such as: "hello" on one line and "world" on the next.

Comment: If your code *does not compile*, you should specify the exact error messages you recieve from the compiler.

Answer (score 4):

In your function `tokenise` -

```
if(str[start] == "/o"){
```

What is `"/o"` you compare with? It should be `'\0'`.

```
if(str[start] == '\0'){
```

And in `else` your function does not `return` anything , therefore , in that case UB.

You function doesn't have any loop or use recursion to iterate over array ,therefore , your logic doesn't seem to achieve anything close .

Comment: That's hardly the biggest problem in this code, one cannot compare `char` and `const char*` using `==` or assign them using `=`.

Comment: @szczurcio  That's the point of it . he should compare with null character  . And it doesn't make any sense as OP's logic is broken .

Comment: Ah yes, didn't notice the single quote, you're right.

Answer (score 3):

You have many problems with your code:

```
else {
    result = str[start];
}
```

No return value. That is undefined behaviour.

```
str[start] == '\o'
```

Thats incorrect as you want to compare to the EOS null termination character
Do this instead:

```
str[start] == '\0'
```

Lastly, if you want your tokenise function to write into `result`, you need to pass a pointer to `result`, not the value of `result`.

ps: semantic errors aside, your function does nothing resembling what you want. Look into loops and their implementation.

Comment: `\0` isn't EOF, but EOS.